# How do I update a Label from within a BackgroundWorker thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, backgroundworker

When I used WinForms, I would have done this in my `bg_DoWork` method:

```
status.Invoke(new Action(() => { status.Content = e.ToString(); }));
status.Invoke(new Action(() => { status.Refresh(); }));
```

However in my WPF application I get an error saying that `Invoke` does not exist for `Label`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you.

To Execute synchronously:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { status.Content = e.ToString(); }))
```

To Execute Asynchronously:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { status.Content = e.ToString(); }))
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the capabilities already built into the `BackgroundWorker`. When you "report progress", it sends your data to the `ProgressChanged` event, which runs on the UI thread. No need to call `Invoke()`.

```
private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    bgWorker.ReportProgress(0, "Some message to display.");
}

private void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    status.Content = e.UserState.ToString();
}
```

Make sure you set `bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true` to enable reporting progress.

Comment: This. Because you don't really want to be updating UI controls across different threads.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using WPF, I'd suggest looking into DataBinding.

The "WPF way" to approach this would be to bind the label's `Content` property to some property of your model. That way, updating the model automatically updates the label and you don't have to worry marshalling the threads yourself.

There are many articles on WPF and databinding, this is likely as good a place to start as any: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/hello-bound-world/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

`Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { status.Content = e.ToString(); }))`

instead of `status.Invoke(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You really should think about using the power of "Data Binding" in WPF.

You should be updating an object in your view model and binding that to your user interface control.

See MVVM Light. Simple and easy to use. Don't code WPF without it.

Comment: You don't *need* any fancy framework to use the MVVM design pattern. Although it does make some things a little bit easier to manage.