# Severe lag trying to Retrieve GPU data with hardware monitor api

Tags: c#, gpu

Getting Severe LAG and Freezes when i enable my Gpu data retrieval With Open Hardware Monitor API: Any ideas Why?

```
        //Causes Severe Lag
        //GPU Usage openhardwaremonitor 
        //---------------------------
        Computer c = new Computer()
        {
            GPUEnabled = true
        };
        c.Open();

        foreach (var hardware in c.Hardware)
        {
            if (hardware.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuNvidia)
            {
                hardware.Update();
                foreach (var sensor in hardware.Sensors)
                    if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Level)
                        label27.Text = sensor.Name + ": " +sensor.Value.GetValueOrDefault();
            }
            //
            if (hardware.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuAti)
            {
                hardware.Update();
                foreach (var sensor in hardware.Sensors)
                    if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Level)
                        label27.Text = sensor.Name + ": " + sensor.Value.GetValueOrDefault();
            }
        }
        //----------------------------
```

Comment: Are you running with administrator privileges : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296543/get-cpu-temperature-using-open-hardware-monitor

Comment: Yes i am running with administrator privileges, Still causes freeze if i comment out the code everything works fine but as soon as this code is up it freezes

Comment: Where does it freeze ?

Comment: as soon as it displays the Data then Entire Application freezes for a second.i am trying it on a clean application aswell just to see

Comment: Are you using latest version : https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor

Comment: ok i,ve got 0 freeze if i code a Try Method with a Catch this might have solved the problem

Comment: Yes i am using the latest version

Comment: If the code is running a separate thread to the GUI thread - then trying to directly update a label will cause an exception : see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398006/how-do-i-update-a-label-from-within-a-backgroundworker-thread.

Comment: Try using some logging with stopwatches when getting values from you sensors.

Or use some profiling tooling to inspect your code.